# Change color for events Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I want to change color for events when using fullcalendar. The events are rendering successfully into the calendar. However I want to have a different color like 'red'. How do I do this?

```
   var getBookingsID = function (id, type) {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        table.clear().draw();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "/api/Bookings/" + id + '/' + type,
            success: function (data) {
                var dataToJson = JSON.parse(data);

                var cal = $('#calendar');

                cal.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                cal.fullCalendar('renderEvents', dataToJson, true);


                table.rows.add(dataToJson);
                table.columns.adjust().draw();
            }
        });
    };
```

Working code with new colors for fullcalendar.io but need help with inserting the events in datatable now.

```
var getAllBookings = function () {
    var cal = $('#calendar');
    cal.fullCalendar('removeEvents');

    cal.fullCalendar('addEventSource',
            {
                id : 'OpenBookings',
                url: '/api/Bookings/',
                color: 'red',
                textColor: 'white'
            }
    );
    cal.fullCalendar('refetchEventSources', "OpenBookings");
};
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display . If you want to make each event have different colours then https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object. You can also specify colours per event source if you were to use event sources. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object . What have you tried or researched so far? Lots of info in the existing documentation, as I've pointed out...

Comment: P.S. Why are you using renderEvents and removeEvents instead of just defining an ajax data source directly (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed , or per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function if you require greater customisation of the ajax request) especially as when you asked your last question only a few days ago you were doing it sensibly (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292112/issue-loading-events-fullcalendar-io) using eventSources

Comment: The reason I'm not using eventsources with url is cause I need the JSON data for a datatable I have also it won't update when using that way.

Comment: " it won't update"....you can just call "refetchEvents" whenever you want to manually update it from the server. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchEvents . Anyway if you need the data for more than one thing you can still do that, just use the events-as-a-function model and simultaneously send the event data elsewhere at the same time you pass it to fullCalendar.

Comment: I got it to work with different color for the new events now. However I'm not sure how to make it work with inserting the events into my datatable too now that I use Fullcalendar ajax call instead. Could you please show my how you would do it? See the new code in my post question.

Comment: well please edit the question to show your current code so I can understand what you did, and maybe I can help

Comment: well actually if you read my later comment I was suggesting you did it according to this kind of template: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function (events as a function) so that you have direct access to the data returned by ajax, before you pass it to fullCalendar.